# Product of Sum equal to Sum of Product

Tags: inequality

Under what conditions is:

$a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + \ldots + a_nb_n = (a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_n)(b_1 + b_2 + \ldots + b_n)$

Some simple examples where the equality is met are:

$1\cdot1 + 0\cdot0 = (1+0)(1+0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(a_1+a_2+ \cdots + a_n)(b_1+b_2+ \cdots + b_n) = a_1b_1+a_1(S-b_1)+a_2b_2+a_2(S-b_2) + \cdots + a_nb_n + a_n(S-b_n)$$

where $S = \sum b_i$.

We need $S-b_i = 0$ for all $i$. Adding gives $(n-1)S = 0$ or $n = 1$ or $S = 0$.

Comment: $S-b_i = 0$ for all $i$ is not necessary. It can be that $\sum a_i (S-b_i) = 0$ with $S-b_i \ne 0$.

Comment: Example in initial question breaks this condition, a1 = 1, a2 = 0, b1 = 1, b2 = 0. Condition from @becko works. Thanks.

Comment: @Logan Unless this answer is edited, it should not be accepted because it has a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @SandeepSilwal answer,

$$\left(\sum_i a_i\right)\left(\sum_i b_i\right) = \sum_i a_i b_i + \sum_i a_i (S - b_i)$$

where $S=\sum_i b_i$. Therefore your equality holds iff:

$$\sum_i a_i (S - b_i) = 0$$